# Extracting data between two strings using SED

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying to extract data between strings using `sed`.

```
sed -n '/SUBCASE 1/,/SUBCASE 2/p' file.txt
```

`SUBCASE 1` is repeated in several lines of the document as shown below.

```
SUBCASE 1
.

.
.
.

SUBCASE 2
.
.

.
.
.

SUBCASE 1

.
...
.

SUBCASE 3
```

How do I extract the data between SUBCASE 1 and SUBCASE 2?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/SUBCASE 1\(.*\)SUBCASE 2/\1/'
```

or

```
sed -n '/^SUBCASE 1$/,/^SUBCASE 2$/p' file.txt
```